# Spring boot mail configuration

Tags: email, spring-boot

I am working on an assignment that sends an email to a user from Gmail smtp with the below configuration.

```
mail:
    host:smtp.gmail.com 
    port:587
    username:xxxxx@gmail.com
    password: *********
    protocol: smtp
    tls: true
        properties.mail.smtp:
            auth: true
            starttls.enable: true
            ssl.trust: smtp.gmail.com
```

It's sending the mail successfully to the end user from the **"xxxxx@gmail.com"**. But my requirement is to send the email with the same smtp server configuration but the **Email Addresses From** **yyyyy@gmail.com** ,**"zzzz@gmail.com"** and **"aaaaa@gmail.com"** instead of **"xxxxx@gmail.com"**. Currently recipient is receiving the mail from **"xxxxx@gmail.com"**.

Info: All the Email Addresses are fetched at runtime based on the user logged-in to the system .
**yyyyy@gmail.com** ,**"zzzz@gmail.com"** and **"aaaaa@gmail.com"**

```
message.setTo(to);
message.setFrom("yyyyy@gmail.com");
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setText(content, isHtml);
javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 option but it is not advisable to use.

In this option you have to manually add alias of all the user in your xxxxx@gmail.com account.
After that you can change from email address.

Refer This Link :[Send emails from a different address or alias](http://%20https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)